# Monero hashrate falls dramatically on Azure Windows 10 Pro

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, mining, hashrate, monero-network-hashrate

I am mining Monero offline using *./monerod --ofline* on a Windows 10 Pro virtual machine with 2 VCUs in Microsoft Azure.

Mining is performed in M2SYS using the *start_mining* command with 2 threads (this is the maximum).

I use *show_hr* to view the hash rate.

The initial hash rate average was 65 h/s. I left it running overnight and noticed that at somepoint the hashrate dropped to 17 h/s. This was an instant drop and not a general tapering off.

I am trying to understand why this drastic hash rate fall has happened? I initially thought this could be an issue with cloud hosting when a session is not active however this makes no sense to me as most servers run efficiently without a user being logged in in an active session.

I have since used *stop_mining* and *start_mining 2* to restart mining. However, the hashrate is still much lower than when I first started yesterday. Any ideas? Could this be a timing coincidence with a general change in the monero hashrate - if so, how do I comfirm this?

Comment: I also have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Mining of cloud based virtual servers will always be poor and susceptible to changes in HR. With virtual servers you are *sharing* CPU resources, and with CrytoNight, you need 2MB CPU cache per thread for optimal performance. A virtual server will never give you exclusivity over CPU cache, hence you'll see changes. Further, most hosting companies forbid mining, so If they detect it, they'll drop your resources.

TL;DR never mine on cloud virtual servers.

Comment: I would disagree with you jtgrassie. I do confirm cloud mining is a bad idea for the obvious reasons you mention, however I doesn't mean we should never mine on virtual server. I do myself on my home esxi farm by using only one mining VM per host, and configuring vCPU such as I can load my host up to its limit. I didn't face any huge hashrate fluctuations. Others would limit their vCPU number to leave enough cache and threads for other vms, but I needed RAM when I builded the esxi cluster, so almost all my CPUs were free to load.

Comment: The user was asking about cloud mining on virtual servers (azure in this case). That's what I was answering.

Comment: True. But your final statement is shortened than this complete explanation and could be misleading for other users. It should be never mine on cloud virtual servers.